# Shipping options have minus in front of them on Paypal Payment review

Tags: shipping, paypal, development, paypal-express

I have Paypal set up on my store and i have an issue with the drop down list in the payment review section of the checkout process when paying with a paypal account.

The costs look like they are being subtracted because there is a hyphen in front of them, when they actually are not.

How do i get rid of these hyphens please?

[image: Example]

Thanks Tom

Comment: If you switch back to the standard [un-edited] Magento theme, do the hyphens still show up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the actual shipping method is not being displayed, only the prices. Take a look at the design file and see what it's `echo`ing in those `<option>`s. My guess is that there's a typo, it's not being echoed, or something along those lines.

Comment: This would make sense actually because the shipping types name was being repeated twice I left the shipping options method name empty. Ill have a look thanks